# Disabled link in Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's Pagination style.  The documentation says to create the page list like so:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The first two links, the left arrow and the 1, should be disabled.  When I incorporate it into my django template though, those two are still usable.  Clicking them sends the user to the top of the page just like any other anchor link with an id "#".  I think I still have to have the  there in order for Bootstrap to style it correctly.

Is there a way to write this so that when the user clicks one of the disabled "buttons" it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the docs, those buttons are just disabled manually. It has nothing to do with the `.pagination` styling.

You could use that

```js
$('.pagination .disabled a, .pagination .active a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note: If you use an ajax based pagination you have to put this piece of code in the update handler or use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) instead

Comment: Note: If you use a ajax based pagination you have to put this piece of code in the update handler.

Comment: Good solution! Don't forget to change the `href=""` of the link to `#` if the page doesn't exist. Otherwise SEO crawlers pick them up and give you negative points for this. Another thing you could do is to make the above javascript more strict. Use `$('ul.pagination li.disabled a, ul.pagination li.active a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   });`. So add `ul` and `li` before the classes.

Comment: This worked like a charm where every other result I looked up for failed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you write the html dynamically server side (with django for example) and you don't want to use javascript you could do this:

```
pseudo code:
if (Model.HasNext()) {
   <li> // normal link
      <a href="www.someurl.com/page=i">next</a>
   </li>
} else {
   <li class="disabled"> // disabled link
      <a href="javascript: void(0)">next</a>
  </li>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, `$('a').parent().addClass('disabled');` works fine as well

Answer (score 6):

As a reference, here is [what Bootstrap does](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/df7cfe86525252034cf85a365d09a4c2485116b4/less/buttons.less#L43-L51):

```
&.disabled,
&[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none; // Future-proof disabling of clicks
  .opacity(.65);
  .box-shadow(none);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Just add the `btn disabled` classes to each link you need to disable.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.disabled a').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For PHPLD v 4.2 I used the following code to show Bootstrap 3 pagination

```
{* Display Paging Links *}
<ul class="pagination">
<li>{paginate_prev id="MainPaging"}</li>
{paginate_middle id="MainPaging" format="page" prefix="" suffix="" link_prefix="
<li>"link_suffix="</li>" current_page_prefix="
<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">"current_page_suffix="</a></li>"}
<li>{paginate_next id="MainPaging"}</li>
</ul>
```